# missing a fundamental understanding on wireshark plus ubertooth

Tags: wireshark

I have a very stupid, yet important question to ask: 
With Wireshark one can already analyse bluetooth pakets. Why do people still combine Wireshark with Ubertooth to analyse Bluetooth pakets?
Is there someone who is very familiar with Ubertooth/Wirshark, and can resolve my confusion?
Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: jbm, you might want to turn your comments into an answer, as it correctly answers the question.  (I.e., you can do "passive" sniffing of third-party traffic with Ubertooth, which you can't do with the Linux sniffing devices you get from libpcap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark "can capture Bluetooth traffic *to or from your machine*" (the one running Wireshark). As opposed to Ubertooth+Wireshark, "to passively capture Bluetooth traffic between *other* machines". Emphasis mine. Reference [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth).

If you have some Wi-Fi experience, the Ubertooth+Wireshark could somewhat be compared to capture in Wi-Fi "monitor mode" (rather than "promiscous" or "normal" modes).

Or if this Wi-Fi analogy I made does not speaks to you: with Wireshark only, you'll see traffic between your PC running Wireshark and the devices [it is bonded/paired with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_and_bonding). With Ubertooth+Wireshark you'll sniff third-party traffic to/from devices you are *not* paired with.

EDIT:

> "Are you sure that with wireshark one can only capture packets between
>   his own device and the device his device is connected to? It seems to
>   me I've captured network communication of my colleague's
>   computer(coming from a third party so to speak)...while his computer
>   is connected to wlan"

@Kindermann **Yes, I am 100% positively sure**, as Guy Harris (who knows is stuff about all this) is in his comment bellow.

Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) is fundamentally different from Bluetooth (IEEE 802.15) or Ethernet (IEEE 802.3). Is it not handled by the same userland middleware/tools nor the same kernel parts (for which Bluetooth is a super-charged serial port with some added layers, for example PAN/BNEP profile to make it "look alike" TCP/IP stuff). **It is only by the - Oh so many virtues - of wireshark that all this look the same, as just "sniffing". Under the hood, it's very different.**

Wireshark, at least on Linux, can also "sniff" USB traffic. How is the "Universal Serial Bus" aka USB from your mouse/keyboard/mass storage related to 802.11 Wi-Fi or wired 802.3 Ethernet? It is not. At all. Yet Wireshark can "sniff" it. Many thanks to wiresharks developers for making all this look so *transparent*, because wireshark is mostly about *dissecting protocols*, as opposed to *what the underlying design (and actual sniffing/capture process) is*.

Comment: Are you sure that with wireshark one can only capture packets between his own device and the device his device is connected to? It seems to me I've captured network communication of my colleague's computer(coming from a third party so to speak)...while his computer is connected to wlan

Comment: For Bluetooth, using the standard libpcap mechanisms for capturing on Linux, yes, we're sure.  "I can capture third-party traffic on WLAN" doesn't mean you can do that with Bluetooth adapters. On some (but not all) operating systems, you can put a WLAN adapter into "monitor mode" and capture third-party traffic.  That option does not appear to be available for regular Bluetooth adapters.

Comment: "Many thanks to wiresharks developers for making all this look so transparent, because wireshark is mostly about dissecting protocols, as opposed to what the underlying design (and actual sniffing/capture process) is." Presumably you mean "many thanks to libpcap's developers", as the underlying sniffing mechanisms are largely hidden from applications (tcpdump, Wireshark, etc.) by libpcap.  What the Wireshark developers did was add dissectors for the protocols in question (802.11, Bluetooth, USB, etc.).